# How to have Pig store rows in HBase as strings not bytes?

Tags: hbase, apache-pig, hbasestorage

If I use the `hbase shell` and issue:

```
put 'test', 'rowkey1','cf:foo', 'bar'
scan 'test'
```

I will see the result as a string, not in bytes.

If I use `happybase` and issue:

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection('<hostname>')
table = connection.table('test')
table.put('rowkey2', {'cf:foo': 'bar'})
for row in table.scan():
    print row
```

I will see the result as a string, not in bytes.

I have data in hive that I ran an aggregation on and stored on HDFS via:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'aggregation_test'
SELECT device_id, device_name, sum(device_cost)
FROM devices
GROUP BY device_id, device_name
ORDER BY device_id, device_name
```

However, if I issue the following in Pig:

```
A = LOAD 'aggregation_test' USING PigStorage(',') as (device_id:chararray, device_name:chararray, device_sum:int);
STORE A INTO 'hbase://aggregation_test'
USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
    'cf:device_name, cf:device_sum');
```

Scans in `hbase shell` and in `happybase` result in bytes, not in string.

I can't even search on a row key that is a string.

How can I use Pig and HBaseStorage to store data from HDFS into HBase as strings not bytes?

Answer (score 0):

> Scans in hbase shell and in happybase result in bytes, not in string.

I suspect that the problem is with your source data, not with the Pig process itself.

Why not copy your source data to local disk and inspect? Something like:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /<>/aggregation_test /tmp/aggregation_test
cat /tmp/aggregation_test/*
```

Another check: does the row count in HBase tally with what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using HBaseBinaryConverter option? Something like:

```
store CompleteCases_f into 'hbase://user_test' using
    org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
        'id:DEFAULT id:last_modified birth:year gender:female gender:male','-caster HBaseBinaryConverter'
);
```